# How to reload a prompt if user selects the cancel button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I reload a prompt if the user selects the cancel button?

For example I have a prompt named divisor and I am prompting the user for a number. If they click cancel how can I automatically reload the prompt?

Comment: How are you loading the prompt in the first place?  Is it in a function?  Just call the function again when they cancel the prompt.

Comment: Use a while loop and only exit it if they've entered something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function promptX(){
  var proceed = confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?");
  if (proceed) {
    //proceed
    alert('ok');
  } else {
    //don't proceed
    promptX();
  }
}

promptX();
```